# How to create sqlite table in Django automatically?

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite

Im using Django 2.0. My task is to write a large dataset that after being analized it'll be dropped every day. I've decided to write that data in SQLite using database routers that generates the file automatically but it does not create the model table and throws an OperationalError cause the table does not exist. Which (if someone had a similar situation) should be a nice solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Couldn't you just test for the table, and then create if needed before trying to write data to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @SuperStew suggestion, something like this should work:

```
# in settings.py
import os

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}

db_path = DATABASES['default']['NAME']
if not os.path.isfile(db_path):
    open(db_path, 'wb').close()
```

Comment: Thanks both (Marat and SuperStew), took that example and made some improvements